# Calling a function when a scrollbar appears in an IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got an IFrame, in the onload event i set the height of the frame:

```
function resizeFrame() { $("#iframeID").height($("#iframeID").contents().find("body").outerHeight(true)); }
```

**Problem is:**
When the content of the frame is increasing without a postback (javascript or Async Postback with Ajax), a scrollbar appears.
I found a solution for Firefox:

```
document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.addEventListener("overflow", resizeFrame, false);
```

But i can't find a solution for IE 7+8
Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly applying it to the iframe's body didn't work.
But i found a plugin where you can apply it to any element on the site: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

So that's my code(solution) now:

```
function initFrame() 
{      
  resizeAppFrame();

  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0)                          
    $(function() { $(appFrame.document.body).resize(resizeAppFrame) }) //IE
  else
    document.getElementById("applicationFrame").contentWindow.addEventListener("overflow", resizeAppFrame, false);  //FireFox
}
function resizeAppFrame()
{
  $("#iFrameID").height($("#iFrameID").contents().find("body").outerHeight(true));
}
```

...

```
<iframe name="appFrame" id="iFrameID" onload="initFrame();" frameborder="0" src="TestFrame.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can fall back on the jQuery's resize() event handler, applied on the iframe's body. It is meant to work with the window element only, but [seems to work with any element on IE](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/7c1e54e95e6b56e4?pli=1).